# Add Email Follow Up to Meeting Completion

Tags: activity

When completing a Meeting Activity, at the bottom where you can Schedule Follow-up, would it be possible to add Email to the "Schedule Follow-Up Activity". 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Emails aren't usually editable so they might not make good scheduled activities. Two alternatives:

1. Use the scheduled reminders feature (https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/) to remind somebody to send the email at the future time, or to actually send the email, depending on what you want.
2. Add a new activity type called something like "send an email", and schedule that as the followup instead, just as a visual note.

Comment: Technically you are correct, as the description for the Activity Type of E-mail says "Sent E-mail."  However, now in the general New Activity list I've got listed "E-mail" and "Send an email", which is also going to make training and reporting more interesting.

Comment: I guess you could label it "Placeholder reminder to send an email". A bit verbose but less confusing.